# App Scripts CC or multiple TO not working

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I've searched a little bit on it and I can't find resolution. I am trying to add CC to send email and tried few things but nothing was working. Now sure what am I doing wrong, here is how it looks like and what I've tried.

```
var TO_ADDRESS = "email1@gmail.com";// email to send the form data to
```

Send email:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: TO_ADDRESS,
  subject: "TEXT",
  replyTo: String(mailData.email),
  htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData)
});
```

What I've tried and didn't worked:

1 Tried to add a variable `TO_CC` but it didn't worked

```
var TO_ADDRESS = "email1@gmail.com";// email to send the form data to
var TO_CC = "email2@gmail.com";// cc email to send the form data to
...
 MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: TO_ADDRESS,
      cc: TO_CC,
      subject: "TEXT",
      replyTo: String(mailData.email),
      htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData)
    });
```

2 Tried to add multipe email into `to` and it didn't worked either:

```
 var TO_ADDRESS = "email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com";// email to send the form data to
    ...
     MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: TO_ADDRESS,
          subject: "TEXT",
          replyTo: String(mailData.email),
          htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData)
        });
```

3 Tried to hardcode it to check if it works, but no luck

```
 MailApp.sendEmail({
              to: email1,
              cc: email2,
              subject: "TEXT",
              replyTo: String(mailData.email),
              htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData)
            });
```

I've checked this document from google: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app
I can see that they state below:

- `to   String  the email address of the recipient or a comma-separated list of email addresses to be the recipients`
- `cc   String  a comma-separated list of email addresses to CC`

If anyone could point me where is the issue here? I know it is very simple but just can't see it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The three methods that you provided worked for me. Let's say that you use the first option when sending an email. Can you test your code without `replyTo: String(mailData.email),` so that it would look like this [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aOZb.png) to see if it would work? If not, please share the error that you'll get.

Comment: I figured it out, when you mentioned it. I've commented `replayTO` but it was still there, I didn't realise that I need to "Deploy" it every time so I was working with the same script. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had to press "Deploy" button and create new link for any edits that I did, so I was working with the old version every time. Just pressing save not going to update it.